# Rewriting for loop with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to rewrite the following code:

```
    for(i = 0; i < grounds.length; i++) {
        grounds[i].show();
    }
```

with a forEach method in a way:

```
grounds.forEach(**what should i post here?**);
```

Full code:

```
 class Ground {
        constructor(x, y, sizeX, sizeY) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.sizeX = sizeX;
            this.sizeY = sizeY;
        }

        show() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(138, 75, 13)";
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.sizeX, this.sizeY);
        }
    }
}


let ground;
let grounds = [];

function generateGround() {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ground = new Ground(0 + i * 40, canvas.height - 30, 40, 30);
        grounds.push(ground);
    }
}

generateGround();

function draw() {

    for(i = 0; i < grounds.length; i++) {
        grounds[i].show();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

I read few examples, but i can't find a way to execute show() method for each ground element.

Comment: A `for of` loop would be more forward thinking, as there `async/await` compatible, foreach is a step backwards in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an anonymous function which takes a parameter `item` (or whatever you want to call it) then call `item.show()`:

```
grounds.forEach(item => item.show())
```

Older browsers may not support arrow functions - in that case, do this instead:

```
grounds.forEach(function(item) {
    item.show();
})
```

Comment: Fixed @wiesson.